# complex algebra with Solve function

Tags: equation-solving

I wanted to solve this complex expression for L,

```
Solve[(1/(R + (1/Iwc)) + (1/(R + IwL)))^-1 == R, L]
```

where I is sqrt(-1)

and mathematica is out putting {}. Does anyone know what this output means? or how to solve such an expression with mathematica.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `IwL` is not the same thing as `I w L` or `I*w*L`.